# Uploading CSV File to S3 using Rest Assured

Tags: amazon-s3, rest-assured

I am trying to replicate a postman put request where it is uploading a csv file on the S3 location given by a code.

The url is like https://us-east-1-e9qpbo283.s3.amazonaws.com/bulk-bucket/a4894e7b-7e42-4fcc-9f84-e7n00db6d581/input/file

with query params as `{X-Amz-Date=20200226T113914Z, X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256, X-Amz-Signature=<Some Signature>, X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost, X-Amz-Security-Token=<SOME TOKEN HERE>, X-Amz-Credential=ASIAV7AYOYCBQB4VDGD7%2F20200226%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request, X-Amz-Expires=3600}`

But I am always getting 400 bad request. The request also doesn't require any other auth token. Can someone help me with this.

I have already visited and tried the links

[Uploading file to S3 using Rest Assured multipart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151838/uploading-file-to-s3-using-rest-assured-multipart)

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rest-assured/MPzbiozclqg

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/627

**My Code is like**

```
File uploadFile = new File("/home/beast/Downloads/locations.csv");

RequestSpecification request = given().urlEncodingEnabled(false).              
 config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
                .multiPart("file", uploadFile, "csv");
Response r = request.put(URL);
```

[image: Request from postman]

**PS: The error is of Signature Mismatch.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing the CSV as a binary file in the body you can just open the file and pass it in the body like in below example:

```
  RestAssured.urlEncodingEnabled = false;
    File uploadFile = new File("COMPLETE_FILE_PATH");
    Response response = given().contentType("text/csv")              .config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
                    .body(uploadFile)
                    .when()
                    .put(uploadUrl)
                    .then().extract().response();
```