# Sending post request to S3 with RestAssured

Tags: java, amazon-s3, rest-assured

I want to reproduce a postman call with RestAssured.
The call send some text parameters and a file parameter to upload file to S3

It look like this :
[image]

In rest assured I've done this :

```
Response response = RestAssured
            .given()
            .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
            .header("Connection","keep-alive")
            .formParams(credentials) // credentials is a hashmap containing all the text params
            .multiPart("file",new File("src/main/resources/media/desktop_1.webm"),"video/webm") 
            .post();
```

I'm getting this error `NFOS: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://s3HIDDENURL: Connection reset by peer: socket write error avr. 26, 2022 3:40:29 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryExecute`

I've also tried to change the file from multipart to formParam like this : `.formParam("file",new File("src/main/resources/media/desktop_1.webm"),"video/webm")`

I've got another error `Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type multipart/form-data`

Comment: Seems to be some issues with posting forms through RestAssured: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/841

Comment: any other way to send such request ?

Comment: @HamzaAmami check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/60508675/7927294